# Is there any way to change the log message format in scrapy?

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy, scraper, twisted.internet

I would like to modify the scrapy log messages to contain user id at the beginning of it.  for example, instead of this

```
2015-03-03 17:09:34+0530 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
```

Is it possible to make it appear like

```
**user_id**:2015-03-03 17:09:34+0530 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
```

Additionaly, is there a way to log only the user messages; i.e, Log only the messages I want logged which I will supply from the code?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scrapy uses Twisted's logging systems which are build on top of logging standard library. I don't have answer for you, how to change date format of logs generated by scrapy itself.

For you second question I might have answer. I think you should completely silence scrapy logging by setting

```
LOG_ENABLED = False
```

in you settings.py. Then, configure logging module for yourself (on top of spider module)

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)8s\t%(message)s', )
```

and then log using `logging.log`, `logging.info`, `logging.debug` etc.

I leave to you figure out desired logging format.

Answer (score 3):

In settings.py add

```
LOG_FORMAT = user_id +' %(asctime)s %(levelname)8s\t%(message)s'
```

More info https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html#logging-settings